# Can't assign datakey of a grid view from a property class inside another property class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have just created a property class with a property class inside that and a property element
and i m using this class as a list for binding into gridview. while binding it is working clearly. but while assigning this property into a data key its throwing an error like "**DataBinding: 'VNMEntity.MemberScheme' does not contain a property with the name 'Member.ID'.**"
I am giving the grid view details below.

"
 `<asp:GridView ID="grdMemberScheme" CssClass="Gridheader" PagerStyle-CssClass="pagination" OnPageIndexChanging="grdSchemeList_PageIndexChanging" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10"
                                AutoGenerateColumns="false"  Width="100%" runat="server"` **DataKeyNames="Member.ID,Scheme.SchemeTypeID"** `OnRowCommand="grdMemberScheme_RowCommand">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Member ID" DataField="Member.ID" />` "

Comment: Could you provide code from your code behind where this exception is being thrown

Comment: While Binding list into grid view `            grdMemberScheme.DataSource = _MemberScheme;
            grdMemberScheme.DataBind();`

Comment: Could you give the class definition for _MemberScheme? So without any datakeynames being assigned the grid binds ok? @praveenp

Comment: yap it binds fine with out data key.